# Finding a value of integer and passing that value to another integer in a loop But the integer gets reset to initial value

Tags: c++

Finding a value of integer and passing that value to another integer in a loop.But as soon as i move to next point in loop,the value of integer get reset to initial value.I am unable to find reasons.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t,n,z=0;
    int k=0;
    cin>>t;
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        cout<<"k before="<<k<<endl;
        int z=i+2+k;
        int k=z;
        cout <<"k after="<<k<<endl;
        cout <<z<<endl;
    }
}
```

Here,for i=0,z=2 and k=2.But at next iteration k becomes again 0.

Answer (score 2):

You are *shadowing* the outer `z` and `k` with the ones you declare within the `for` loop body. So "k after" refers to the newly declared `k`, "k before" refers to the one in the outer scope.

Writing

```
z=i+2+k;
k=z;
```

in the loop is the fix.

Some compilers warn you of this - do you have warnings set to an appropriate level?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in answer by [Basthseba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57851636/11426913) there are different variables inside and outside scope of for loop.

**In the first iteration:**

In the first iteration Of the loop 'k' is accessed before declaration of 'k from for loop', therefore k from line `int k=0;`, the one before loop, value is displayed.

**In the second iteration:**

Now the 'k' from line `int k = z;` is already declared in the last iteration therefore value of 'k' that was assigned `k=z` which was derived from `i+2+k` will be displayed that is 2.

Similarly 'z' can be interpreted as the 'z' belonging to main function and 'z' belonging to **for loop** inside main function.

Now in a perfect world we should not be allowed to declare variables inside the loop since it would count as multiple declaration inside the same scope, but as the language has been build, the variables declared inside loops are only actually declared in the first iteration and all declaration in subsequent iteration are ignored.

**Suggestion:** When using variables in child scopes like loops or conditional statements either declare variables by different names or do not declare them inside child scopes at all.